# How do shortcuts to cmd.exe store settings for the program?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

If you right click a shortcut to cmd.exe, you'll see not only the regular properties that you'd see for every shortcut, but also properties for the console emulator.

[image: A screenshot of the cmd.exe right-click properties]

My question is, how is this actually possible? I've never seen another Windows program work this way. Is cmd taking advantage of an infrequently used API, or does Windows have special handling for this program and this program alone?

Comment: Open c:\windows\system32. Find CMD.EXE. Look its properties. You will be surprised... Then select any console EXE (for example, convert.exe), Right click - Send to - Desktop (create shortcut). Look at created shortcut properties - you will be surprised again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; Windows has special handling for *all console applications.* Unlike e.g. Linux programs, each Windows .exe has [a bit in its header](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/?p=19643) that indicates whether this is a "console" or "windowed" executable.

In addition to that, the console windows are not created by CMD itself. (In Linux terms, CMD is a shell/interpreter; it is not a terminal.) Instead, they are automatically shown by CSRSS whenever such a process is launched, although these days the actual UI has been been split out into [ConHost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Console). There is indeed an API that CMD and other console applications use, but it is fully documented and a standard part of the Win32 API.

Windows Explorer – the program that displays these "Properties" dialogs – recognizes console apps from this header field and shows additional settings. (It even shows more settings for 16-bit apps which use NTVDM. Remember .pif files?)

Each newly created console window will pick up [settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/) from under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`, which has subkeys (subfolders) based on the executable name or the initial window title. If there are no matching subkeys, it will also (through some unknown mechanism) pick up settings stored within the shortcut's .lnk file, as in the screenshot you provided.

See also:

- Microsoft DevBlog: [Understanding Windows Console Host Settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/)
- The Old New Thing: [How do I write a program that can be run either as a console or a GUI application?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090101-00/?p=19643)

Comment: What is this "unknown mechanism", I am having a hard time resetting some shortcuts to defaults because of this.